# send information to forked process with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, tcp, pthreads, fork

I have 2 programs, a client and a server, the client can send data to the server, and I want to send all the new data received on the server from one client to the other connected clients with a thread, each connected client has a child process in the server that receives the data, here is an illustration of what I want to do.

server.c :

```
int  main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    Liste *ListeTache;
    int sh_id;
    int i,j;
    size_t sizeMatrix = sizeof_dm(30,100,sizeof(char));
    ListeTache=malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    init_Liste(ListeTache);

    key_t keyfile = ftok("keyFileIpc.txt",10);

    if((sh_id = shmget(keyfile,sizeof(Liste),IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget");
        exit(1);
    }


    if ((ListeTache = shmat(sh_id, NULL, 0)) == (void *) -1) {
        perror("shmat");
        exit(1);
    }
    init_Liste(ListeTache);
    printSharedMem(ListeTache->s);
    //creation de la socket pour le TCP
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sock == -1) {
        perror("socket error\n");
        exit(errno);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };

    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    sin.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sin.sin_port = htons(31470);

    if(bind (sock, (struct sockaddr *) &sin, sizeof sin) == -1) {
        perror("bind()");
        exit(errno);
    }

    if(listen(sock, 3) == -1) {
        perror("listen error\n");
        exit(errno);
    }

    struct sockaddr_in csin = { 0 };
    int idSock;
    socklen_t lg = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    char msg[100];

    do {

        if ((idSock = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &csin, &lg)) == -1) {
            perror("accept error\n");
            exit(errno);
        }

        if (!fork()) {
             close(sock);

            printSharedMem(ListeTache->s);
            printf("i'm here\n");
            // we send here the initial data
            if(send(idSock, ListeTache, sizeof(Liste), 0) < 0) {
              perror("send()");
              exit(errno);
            }
            pthread_t idThread;
            do {

                if(recv(idSock, &paramsReq, sizeof(paramsReq), 0) < 0) {
                    perror("paramsReq :recv error\n");
                    exit(errno);
                }
                  //if recv something from a client then i want to send the change to all the others here

        }
        else
         {
         close(idSock);
         }

    } while (1);

    free(ListeTache);
    ListeTache=NULL;
   shmctl(sh_id, IPC_RMID, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
void *listenServ (void *arg) {
    paramsListenServ params = *((paramsListenServ *) arg);
    paramsRequest paramsReq;

    do {
        if(recv(params.sockId, &paramsReq, sizeof(paramsReq), 0) < 0) {
            perror("recv error\n");
            exit(errno);
        }
        printf("%s \n", paramsReq.requestType);
        if (!strcmp(paramsReq.requestType, "addRequest")) {
            strcpy(&params.s[paramsReq.taskToModify*100], paramsReq.taskText);

            printSharedMemo(params.s);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(paramsReq.requestType, "swapRequest")) {
            char firstTask[100];
            strcpy(firstTask, &params.s[paramsReq.tasksToSwap.firstTask*100]);

            strcpy(&params.s[paramsReq.tasksToSwap.firstTask*100], &params.s[paramsReq.tasksToSwap.secondTask*100]);
            strcpy(&params.s[paramsReq.tasksToSwap.secondTask*100], firstTask);

           printSharedMemo(params.s);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(paramsReq.requestType, "modifyRequest")) {
            strcpy(&params.s[paramsReq.taskToModify*100], paramsReq.taskText);

         printSharedMemo(params.s);
        }
        else if (!strcmp(paramsReq.requestType, "deleteRequest")) {
            int i = paramsReq.taskToModify;

            while (i < 29 && strlen(&params.s[i * 100]) != 0) {
                strcpy(&params.s[i*100], &params.s[(i + 1)*100]);
                i++;
            }

            strcpy(&params.s[(paramsReq.head - 1)*100], "");
            printSharedMemo(params.s);
        }

        /*printf("Message reçu du serveur : %s\n", msg);

        memset(msg,0, sizeof msg);*/
    } while (1);

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    //creation d'un socket ppour le TCP
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    Liste *ListeTache;
    ListeTache=malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    init_Liste(ListeTache);
    int j;
    if(sock == -1) {
        perror("socket()");
        exit(errno);
    }

    //initialisation de la structure de donné
    struct sockaddr_in sin = { 0 };

    sin.sin_family = PF_INET;
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    sin.sin_port = htons((short)31470);

    //connect to the server
    if(connect(sock,(struct sockaddr *) & sin, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)) == -1) {
        perror("connect()");
        exit(errno);
    }

    // we receive the initial data
    if(recv(sock,ListeTache,sizeof(Liste), 0) < 0) {
        perror("main :recv error\n");
        exit(errno);
    }

    printSharedMemo(ListeTache->s);

    pthread_t idThread;

    paramsListenServ params;
    params.s=ListeTache->s;
    params.sockId = sock;

    // this thread listen to the send that is in the server
    if(pthread_create(&idThread, NULL, listenServ, &params) != 0)
        perror("pthread_create");
    do {

                //do changes

              //we send the new data to the server
            if(send(sock, &paramsReq, sizeof(paramsReq), 0) < 0) {
                perror("send()");
                exit(errno);
            }
        }
        }
    } while(1<=choice && choice<=4);
    close(sock);
    printf("La connexion avec le serveur a bien été fermée ! \n");
    return 0;
}
```

My question is, if I use a thread and put it in a fork, how can the thread get the data sent from one client because the socket change from one client to another?

Comment: In general, mixing threads and forking is a dangerous mixture.  When a child is forked, it has a single thread but a copy of all the data structures, including mutexes and so on, from the original process.  This can mean your thread is  locked out from accessing data that no other thread can access.  Be cautious.  (All that said, I really don't follow quite what you're trying to do.)